# What does "taking a cut on" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "taking a cut on" mean here?

Zomato can make revenues both on advertising on the search platform, as well as by taking a cut on reservations that it successfully makes for those establishments.

Comment: Alina, you need to show evidence that you've made some attempt to access easy-to-find resources: that's one of the site rules.

Comment: Here "cut" means a "commission or fee" that you charge when you make reservations for your clients. "Taking a cut on" means "making money from a commission".

Comment: A cut is usually less than one half, but more than a taste. It's all gangster argot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**taking a cut on**: Typically this means *taking a share of the money.*

In your context, it means Zomato can make revenues by claiming a share of the money resulting from reservations that it successfully makes for those establishments.